# Return List<String> with Spring JdbcTemplate with Select IN

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am getting Incompatible Types Error.

```
Required: List<java.lang.String>
Found: List<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Objectaq>
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
String sql = "SELECT distinct case_name FROM case WHERE case_class IN (:case_class)";
Map<String, List> paramMap = Collections.singletonMap("case_class", listCaseClass);
List<String> cases = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, paramMap, String.class);
```

Comment: Looks like  listCaseClass is not a List of strings, could you post its definition?

Comment: Becauyse you are using the wrong method. `queryForList` returns a `List<Map<String, Object>>`. Also `JdbcTemplate` doesn't support named parameters, so you are probably using the wrong class.

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this:

```
String sql = 
    "SELECT distinct case_name FROM case WHERE case_class IN (:case_class) ";

Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<>();
paramMap.put("case_class", listCaseClass);

List<String> cases = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, paramMap, String.class);
```

i think that case is reserved key if you want use this key as table name should use by double quote like this:

```
String sql = 
        "SELECT distinct case_name FROM \"case\" WHERE case_class IN (:case_class) ";
```